# How can make DECLARE take a value from stored procedure

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures

[image]

How can I make `DECLARE @T` take this value from the stored procedure?

This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetTotlePrice]
    (@Users_Id bigint)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @R TABLE
               (
                   Price bigint,
                   Quantity bigint
               )

    INSERT INTO @R
        SELECT TOP 1000000 
            M.Price, B.Quantity 
        FROM
            Basket B  
        INNER JOIN 
            Medicaments M ON M.Medicament_Id = B.Medicament_Id 
        WHERE 
            @Users_Id = B.Users_Id
        
    SELECT SUM(Price * Quantity) FROM @R
END
```

Comment: How does your Stored Procedure return values? (in result-sets, temporary-tables, `OUTPUT` parameters, `int` return codes?)

Comment: BEGIN
DECLARE @R TABLE
 (
  Price bigint,
  Quantity bigint
 )
 INSERT INTO @R
 SELECT TOP 1000000 
    M.Price,
    B.Quantity 
    From Basket B  INNER JOIN 
    Medicaments M ON M.Medicament_Id = B.Medicament_Id WHERE @Users_Id = B.Users_Id
  
 SELECT SUM(Price * Quantity) From @R

END

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: You forgot to add a Tag for the `DBMS` you are using, whis is probably MS `sql-server`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found my mistake
firstly i nead to return a value in my stored procedure
i add

```
DECLARE @T AS bigint
    SELECT @T = SUM(Price * Quantity) From @R AS TotlePrice
    --SELECT SUM(Price * Quantity) From @R AS TotlePrice
    RETURN @T
```

then

```
DECLARE @return_value bigint
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[sp_GetTotlePrice]
        10
SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

Comment: The `RETURN` from a stored procedure should **only** be used to indicate success (or failure) - you should **NOT** use it to return back a value from a calculation or such. For that, either use an `OUTPUT` parameter, or a returned data set